# Why error in selenium python when using headless

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i try to zoom or unzoom chrome's tab but when i try to run it `headlees` there is error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: chrome is not defined
```

without `headless` working good , is there any idea?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://google.com')


driver.get('chrome://settings/')
driver.execute_script('chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(1.5);')
```

Comment: Check this answer and you might find something to try out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52072722/how-can-i-set-a-zoom-level-on-a-headless-chrome-instance

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you can't set the zoom in headless mode.

## Not working

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://google.com')


driver.get('chrome://settings/')
driver.execute_script('chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(1.5);')
```

## Working

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://google.com')


driver.get('chrome://settings/')
driver.execute_script('chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(1.5);')
```

You see that you are not able to access the `chrome` element in headless mode.

Comment: I know this, but i want to run in background headless

Comment: Why do you need the zoom? You dont see the driver?

Comment: Beacuse i want to show invisible elements , when i scroll only then i can see it